# Azure: move resources from one subscription to another with dependency

Tags: azure

I have 5 VMS with public IP and ssh keys, also k8s cluster and registry to be migrated to other subscription.

Following
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-resource-group-and-subscription

However, publicIP and ssh keys cannot be moved and on removing selecting VMs are also not moving because they are dependent on IPs and others

Answer (score 1):

As the quoted doc details, the resources you want to move must support the move operation first.

Although [Virtual machines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-support-resources#microsoftcompute) can be moved across Subscriptions (with some [constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-limitations/virtual-machines-move-limitations#scenarios-not-supported)), other resources like [AKS clusters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/faq#can-i-move-my-aks-clusters-from-the-current-azure-subscription-to-another), [Standard Public IP resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-support-resources#microsoftnetwork) and SSH Keys cannot.

Re-building or redeploying them in the other Subscription might be the only option here. Do note that automation options like [ARM Templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/overview), [Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/?view=azps-5.0.0) and [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/) might help ease the effort involved.

Answer (score 1):

I had to move a RG that contained VM, connected resources and public ip across subscriptions. The public ip was causing a problem. The solution came up in discussion witht the tech support of Azure :

1. Before the move, go to your Public IP address instance blade, and       click the 'Dissociate' button. This dissociates the public ip from       network interface (in my case).
2. Then perform the move of all of the      resources except for public ip to the target subscription.
3. After       successfull move, perform the move of the public ip across       subscriptions too, to the same RG where all the resources are now.
4. Then go to Public IP address Overview blade again, and click       'Associate'. This will re-associate public ip to network     interface.
5. Typically, if there were no errors during the moves,you should be able to have everything working just as before.

Hope this helps !